# How to install TeX live at newest version?

Tags: latex, tex-live, tlmgr

I installed TeX Live following the [guide on their website](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) using the install-tl script two times. Before the second install I followed the pre-install instructions on that same website, and before any installation I removed the 2017 version that had been installed through Debian repositories.

I need a version of TeX Live >2019. I assumed the install script would install the newest version, but apparently that's not the case, since:

```
$ tlmgr --version
tlmgr revision 49885 (2019-01-31 20:27:00 +0100)
tlmgr using installation: /usr/share/texlive
TeX Live (http://tug.org/texlive) version 2018
```

However, my TeX Live installation is in `./usr/local/texlive/2021`. There is no other directory with a year name in `./usr/local/texlive/`.

I'm really running out of ideas, but I *do* need a newer version of TeX Live. I'm on Debian 10.

Comment: As a test, can you run `/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-darwinlegacy/tlmgr --version` and see if this gives you the correct version? (replace `x86_64-darwinlegacy` with whatever architecture you have)

Comment: If this works, you can add this directory to your path and it should pick up the 2021 version

Comment: thanks, that actually returned the 2021 version. I'll try adding the path tomorrow

Comment: Good to hear! You can find an example of the path setting in the post-install instructions on the website you linked to in your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz advice, but had to find the correct directory for my tlmgr executable. I found that through

```
  $ sudo find -iname 'tlmgr'
```

.. invoked at the root directory. Running

```
  $ /usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-darwinlegacy/tlmgr --version
```

returned the newest version. However, that path was already set as described on the TeX Live page. For it to work, I deleted more directories that had been included in the 2018 installation version of TeX Live. I found those through

```
  $ sudo find -iname '*texlive*'
```

invoked at the root directory. Then

```
  $ tlmgr --version
```

returned the correct version.

Also, don't install TeX Live in `/usr/local`. Install it in your home directory.